# Вызов метода класса из метода вне класса

Tags: c++, arduino

Всех приветствую.

Есть класс Joystick:

```
class Joystick : public Controller
{
    public:
        virtual bool initController(IControllerListener* listener);
        virtual ControllerState getCurrentState();
        JoystickButtons* getButtonsStateFromAnalogState(ControllerState state);
    private:
        void onMiddleButtonPressed();
};
```

Controller:

```
class Controller  
{
    public:
        virtual bool initController(IControllerListener* listener) = 0;
        virtual ControllerState getCurrentState() = 0;
    protected:
        IControllerListener* controller_listener;
};
```

И IControllerListener:

```
class IControllerListener  
{
        public:
                virtual void onControlChanged(Controller* controller, ControllerState state) = 0;
};
```

В классе Joystick объявлен метод onMiddleButtonPressed. Его нужно вызвать из функции вне класса(?):

```
void Joystick::onMiddleButtonPressed() 
{
    this->controller_listener->onControlChanged(this, )
}
// функция вне класса, существует лишь в реализации (cpp файле)
void buttonPressed(){
    this->onMiddleButtonPressed(); 
}
```

Необходимо это сделать из-за того, что функция attachInterrupt

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), buttonPressed, LOW);
```

Имеет такой вид:

```
void attachInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNum, void (*userFunc)(), int mode
```

Если в нее тупо запихивать

```
bool Joystick::initController(IControllerListener* listener) 
{
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), onMiddleButtonPressed, LOW);

    return true;
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> аргумент типа "void (Joystick::*)()" несовместим с параметром типа
> "void (*)()"

То есть, нужно либо функцию

```
void Joystick::onMiddleButtonPressed()
```

преобразовать в void*, либо как-то ее вызвать из buttonPressed. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Функция метод класса работает только в присутствии объекта, над которым её можно вызывать. Как вы хотите вызвать эту функцию без объекта? Передавайте сразу ссылку на сам объект, а не указатель на функцию.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, вот так?     attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), &onMiddleButtonPressed , LOW);

Comment: @AlexGlebe, тогда получается ошибка "аргумент типа "void (Joystick::*)()" несовместим с параметром типа "void (*)()"

Comment: У вас должен быть экземпляр объекта типа Joystick, над которым эту функцию хотите вызвать. Ссылку на этот экземпляр и передавайте.

Comment: Если этот объект в единственном экземпляре, то создайте статическую функцию  `void fun(void){ globalJoyStick . onMiddleButtonPressed ( ) ; }` И её адрес и передавайте.